# Replacing returned active record hash value on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash which is returned by an ruby on rails active record method.

There are a column named 'professional_type', and i want to replace it for another value using a 'each' loop.

But it isn't working.

The code:

```
collection.each_with_index { |(key, value), index |

    if(key.professional_type == 'center_professional')

        key.professional_type = 'test' # does nothing
        key.professional_type << 'test' # this works and concats 'test' string to var

    end

}
```

This is the **collection.inspect** result:

```
[#<Professional id: 105, center_id: 20, name: "ABC", professional_type: "center_professional", created_at: "2014-05-28 12:21:48", updated_at: "2015-01-23 13:12:47", deleted_at: nil>, #<Professional id: 107, center_id: 20, name: "EDFG", professional_type: "center_professional", created_at: "2014-06-03 07:23:31", updated_at: "2015-01-23 13:15:35", deleted_at: nil>]
```

Why if i concat it adds the string to the variable but if i assign a new value it doesn't works? What i am doing wrong?

Thanks for all.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the hash?  I don't get why you're looping, why can't you just do `collection["center_professional"] = test`.  I'm assuming if you show the hash that will become clear.

Answer (score 1):

This should work-

```
collection.map { |key, value|

  if(value == 'center_professional')

    #concat key.professional_type + "<br>"
    collection[key] = 'test'
  end
}
```

Comment: Error: no implicit conversion of Professional into Integer

Comment: 'value' variable is empty

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.collect do  |professional| 
    professional.professional_type = 'test' if(value == 'center_professional') 
    professional
end
```

Comment: i have replaced the 'value' var (doesn't exists) to 'professional' var and doesn't works. Then, i tried deleting the if condition to replace all 'professional_type' values to 'test', and it doesn't works.  :(

Comment: Do you have it deployed on staging server, can look into the matter, otherwise just run collect and check what are you getting.